# Remembering gpg passphrase in Win 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win, gpg-agent

What can I do to forget about typing the passphrase again and again for the commits?

There's [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185424) answer about Kleopatra, but apparently the UI has changed and there's no option for cached passphrase.

Comment: Which OS and what version of GPG??

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [gpg-preset-passphrase](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-preset-passphrase) ([useful link](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/236888))?

Comment: @harrymc 
Latest versions of Win 10 and Ubuntu on WSL2. Latest GPG.

Is there a way for this preset command to run automatically so that I don't have to use it every sign in session?

Comment: I think I found the right method. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got it working.

`~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
default-cache-ttl 34560000
max-cache-ttl 34560000
pinentry-program "/mnt/path/to/bin/pinentry.exe"
```

You need to install Gpg4Win and use `pinentry.exe` provided.

https://www.39digits.com/signed-git-commits-on-wsl2-using-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

In the Stack Overflow post
[Suppress the passphrase prompt in GPG command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072403/suppress-the-passphrase-prompt-in-gpg-command),
this was the
[answer by Marc Tifrea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50334044/165358):

> After a lot of digging I found this command which disables the entry
> prompt on windows(works also for *nix systems):
>
> ```
> --pinentry-mode=loopback
> ```
>
> The full command would be:
>
> ```
> gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase  "PASSWORD" -d -o "PATH\TO\OUTPUT" "PATH\TO\FILE.gpg"
> ```